# Why LiveData Observer is called too many times?

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-livedata

I am using Android LiveData with Room database.
Everything works fine, but only thing is that LiveData observer is called too many times.
I initialized ViewModel inside Activity onCreate function.
Please review my codes and if I've done something wrong.
Thanks

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PersonListViewModel.class);
viewModel.getAll().observe(this, personList->{
    Log.e("PersonRecycler", "Observer called");

    if (personList.size() == 0) {
        lytNoPerson.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        lytNoPerson.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adapterData.resetData(personList);
    }
});
```

I expected this observer called only one time at first load.
And called again whenever I have new updates.
But it is calling many times at first load.
Please check this screenshot below. 
Thanks again.

http://prntscr.com/mjg7dw

Below is ViewModel source code.

```
public class PersonListViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private PersonRepository repository;

    private MutableLiveData<List<Person>> personList;
    private MediatorLiveData<List<Person>> liveDataMerger;

    public PersonListViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        repository = PersonRepository.getInstance(application);

        personList = new MutableLiveData<>();
        liveDataMerger = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Person>> getAll() {
        String createdBy = AppController.getInstance().firebaseUser.getEmail();
        return repository.getAll(createdBy);
    }

    public LiveData<PagedList<Person>> getPagedPerson() {
        return repository.getPagedPerson();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Person>> loadMore(int page) {
        /*
        LiveData<List<Person>> pList = repository.getPersonByPage(page);
        liveDataMerger.addSource(pList, list->{
            liveDataMerger.setValue(list);
        });

        return liveDataMerger;
        */
        return repository.getPersonByPage(page);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<Person>> getPersonList() {
        return personList;
    }
}
```

This is getAll function in repository.

```
public LiveData<List<Person>> getAll(String createdBy) {
        return database.personDao().getAll(createdBy);
    }
```

This is getAll function in Dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PERSON + " WHERE deleted=0 AND createdBy=:createdBy ORDER BY created DESC")
LiveData<List<Person>> getAll(String createdBy);
```

Comment: Edit the question to include the view model code where you post data to your LiveData object.

Comment: sorry, but how can I edit this question?

Comment: There is an edit option in grey right below the question.

Comment: Seems like you post the data in the `repository.getAll` function, can you please include the code of it in the question?

Comment: I updated my question to show all related codes.